# How to stop a Mac app from launching at startup?

Tags: macos, mac, applications, startup, login-items

How can I stop an app from launching at startup when:

- right click on the app on the dock > options > `open at login` is not ticked.
- the app is not on the `login items` list (System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Items)

Comment: What is the app? Conscientious developers sometimes tuck an uninstaller script/app in the installer disk image. If this is an app you can download to a disk image (.dmg) get whatever version is available and see if there is an uninstaller therein.

Comment: What is the app?  There are other ways of starting apps beyond the two in your list.  e.g. it may be in ~/Library/LaunchAgents.